# What's the proper way of expressing the derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've been taught saying is $(f(x))'$ is bad because that's the derivative of a number, $f(x)$ and not the derivative of $f$, I know this. Same thing would happen with $(\log_2(x^2))'$ it is also incorrect right? What we would want to do is $\log_2'(x^2)$? I've heard $\frac{d}{dx}\log_2(x^2)$ is less bad but still bad. Any inputs on this **topic** in general? Doesn't necessarily have to do with this example

Comment: So $\ln(x^2)'=0$, $\ln'(x^2)=\frac1{x^2}$, and $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln(x^2)=\frac2x$. -- For good measuer, I'll throw in a $(x\mapsto \ln(x^2))'(x)$

Comment: I like the notation $f'(x)|_{x = 2}$

Comment: In my opinion the only acceptable notation is $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \log_2(x^2)$. If you for whatever reason must use the prime notation, then define $f(x) := \log_2(x^2)$ and write $f'(x)$.

Comment: and what about if it's only $x^2$? do I write $\frac{d}{dx}x^2$?

Comment: $\big[\log_2(x^2)\big]'$ is clear (at least to me.

Comment: There is no better or worse way as long as the expression is clear. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation

Comment: sure but you would agree that $(log_2(x^2))'$ isn't good at all to express $(x\mapsto \log_2(x^2))'(x)$